# Distance 1-vs-all between two Mat (openCV/C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, distance

In OpenCV C++ I'm trying to compute the distance between one vector to all the rows in a matrix. This is a simplified code:

```
cv::Mat a = (cv::Mat_<int>(1,3) << 1, 2, 3);
cv::Mat b = (cv::Mat_<int>(3,3) << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
float dist = norm(a,b,cv::NORM_L2);
```

It doesn't work because *norm* is expecting input matrices with the same size. Is there a way of obtaining the distance between *a* to each of the rows of *b*? (other than using a naive for loop)

EDIT: What I'd like to have in the end is the row in *b* where same values as in *a* are found. I guess that the best way is to compute the distances and keep those rows whose distance is 0.

Comment: I was wondering if it can be done in a "cleaner" way. Similar to [pdist2](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) in Matlab

Comment: If you only want to find exact matches, why `NORM_L2`? `NORM_L1` is much better, or `bitwise_xor`. That said, I don't know of any way to do that without a loop.